# Delete multiple rows with the same value for a field

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, sql-delete

I'm making an app for Android Devices in which I have to use SQLite.

I have the table Actions with fields Id, `IdEvento`, `IdAccion`, `Activa`.

I want to `DELETE` every row in the table Actions `WHERE IdAccion = X`

How can I do? If I do `DELETE FROM Actions WHERE Id = X` will it delete every row or just the first one that has that value for that field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you provided will delete **all** the rows with `Id = X`.

You can also delete just one, the query for that is:

```sql
DELETE FROM Actions WHERE Id = X LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Solved before your answer, but you're right and that's the answer so I'll accept it. Thank you